# Does VueJs have the concept of Controlled and Uncontrolled Components like React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2

React has the concept of controlled and uncontrolled https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html components.

Where **controlled** are components working within the react model, and state is tracked in the virtual dom.

And uncontrolled are managed outside the virtual dom.

Since Vue also works with a virtual dom is there a wrong way to grab elements (for instance can you use `document.queryBySelector` or `classList.add` like you would if it was vanillajs to manipulate dom)?

Comment: Apparently, the term is [two-way data binding](https://www.koderhq.com/tutorial/vue/two-way-databinding/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong to target elements with vanilla JS like you said but it's not the best practice and Vue may reject any outside attempts to mess with the DOM.

When I need to get an specific element from the DOM and manipulate it using vanilla methods I'll always do from within the Vue structure not from a separate file or script. I'd do it like this or some variation of this:

```
new Vue({
  ...,
  methods:{
    setClass() {
      let elem1 = document.querySelector("#elem1");
      elem1.classList.add("yourClass");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let elem2 = document.querySelector("#elem2");
  }
}
```

If you want to add of remove classes, I would recommend you to use the Class Binding options native to Vue. And if you're dealing with forms, v-model is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

React docs recommends using refs for this ,
Vue too have refs just like react

1. [Vue Template Ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component)
2. [understanding vue refs](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-vue-refs/)